# Click on value in dropdown window using RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

On the following web site: https://www.bhtelecom.ba/index.php?id=7226&a=new
I want to choose second value in drop down window ("Tuzlanski (035)") that apperad after you click on "Sarajevo (033)". I want to do that using RSelenium.

I tried 10 different solutions I found on stackoverflow but non of it works. I thinks it is because it is generated by javascript.

One of my tried solution:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L,
                      browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.bhtelecom.ba/index.php?id=7226&a=new")
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='di']/option[@value='035']")
option$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to click on input field:

```
input <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//input[@class = 'select-dropdown']")
input$clickElement()
```

then options will be visible and you can select them using right `xPath`:

```
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//span[contains(., 'Tuzlanski (035)')]")
option$clickElement()
```

Probably you will may need to use this:

```
Sys.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds
```

if the script will be too quick and will try to select dropdown element before dropdown will appear.

Summary code:

```
input <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//input[@class = 'select-dropdown']")
input$clickElement()

Sys.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds

option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//span[contains(., 'Tuzlanski (035)')]")
option$clickElement()
```

You have also wrong `xPath`:
[image]

Comment: I doesn't work for me: It gives me an error `Error:   Summary: ElementNotVisible` fo the last command (`option$clickelement()`)

Comment: Add `Sys.sleep(5)` after `input$clickElement()`

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: I have found the issue, there was wrong `xPath`, please have a look on the answer